# push multiple objects into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

how can i push multiple object into an array

```
router.post(`/products`, upload.array("photos" , 10), async (req, res) => {
  console.log(res);
  try {
    let product = new Product();
    product.photos.push(req.files[0].location);
    product.photos.push(req.files[1].location);
    await product.save();
    console.log(Product);
    res.json({
      status: true,
      message: "save succes",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

this pushes the 1st and 2nd objects, lets say i have 10 files how can i write a line of code to push the 10 objects at once

```
product.photos.push(req.files[0].location);
product.photos.push(req.files[1].location);
```

how can i make it one line of code like getting the whole array and push to my database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on `req.files`:

```
req.files.forEach(f => product.photos.push(f.location))
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) accepts a variable number of arguments. You can [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) an array as arguments

```js
product.photos.push(...req.files.map(({ location }) => location));
```

---

I'd be inclined to set the `photos` array within your `Product` constructor instead

```js
class Product {
  constructor(photos = []) {
    this.photos = photos;
  }
}

const product = new Product(req.files.map(({ location }) => location));
```